# Ubuntu Phone prevent text messages from lock screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, security, lock-screen, sms

On my Aquaris Ubuntu Phone, text messages quickly pop up on the lock screen.

As I consider this a serious security issue, is it possible to hide any messages from the lock screen?

Thanks for any help.

Cheers,

Thomas

Comment: Looks like a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1573969

Answer (score 1):

It is in System Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Lock Phone -> Notifications and quick settings.

Comment: Even with this set messages still show for about a second. As already stated, I consider this as a security issue, when messages are visible and readable on a lock screen, so I would like to disable it completely.